# Can I subscribe to an event which would tell when an item in a rss feed is added?

Tags: c#, events, rss

I was wondering if there is an event to subscribe to in C# that would be "an item has been added in X rss feed", so an rss reader can deliver the new item as soon as it is delivered.

If I cannot do that, the option would be to read every x seconds/minutes, and compare the last item, but it seems problematic, what if more than one item is delivered ? I imagine I could maybe try to "find" the last known item by going deeper and deeper, and then showing all the new items at once.

Also if I go with the 2nd option, can a too short delay be problematic ? (Ddos detection or just slowing down the computer)

Thanks everyone for your help,

Araly.

Comment: No. What have you tried to do. It's a simple problem, you can probably even do it without libraries...

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I didn't bother to read it in detail. But it looks like someone addressed exactly what you're describing. (And they gave it the worst name ever. But what's in a name?) [http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Consuming-RSS-feeds-with-PubSubHubbub](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Consuming-RSS-feeds-with-PubSubHubbub)

Comment: Well I searched for an event to subscribe to in the documentation of XML in microsoft's website. I also tried to search how to create the delay, but I only found ways to get the process to sleep, and other events I subscribed to cannot be used until program wakes up.